# Can we use the ORM in GAE with Django now?

Tags: django, google-app-engine

Given that django-nonrel has got [JOINs](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/blog/django/2010/04/SimpleDB-backend-and-JOIN-support#disqus_thread) working, does this mean we have M2M fields workable with Django now in GAE?

What other current restrictions does Django have in GAE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This blog post was an [April 1st joke](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/blog/django/2010/04/Writing-a-non-relational-Django-backend)

Some limitations still [apply](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine):

> Many advanced Django features are not supported at the moment. A few of them are:
>
> JOINs
>
> many-to-many relations
>
> multi table inheritance
>
> aggregates
>
> no transactions (but you can use transactions from App Engine's SDK if you really need them)
>
> QuerySet.select_reated